# How to calculate aspect ratio for mobile devices?

Tags: python, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to get the aspect ratio (I.E 16:2, etc) for a series of mobile devices based on their screen resolution.

I applied the following formula

```
widthRatio = int(1080 / math.gcd(1080, 2009))
heightRatio = int(2009 / math.gcd(1080, 2009))
```

This is very simplified, I actually have a function that do it for 17k devices, but the idea is that one.

However in this case the gcd output is 1 both times. Therefore the aspect ration is 1080/2009. Totally not what I wanted. However that works with other types of resolutions.

What's the best way to handle this when the GCD output 1?

Comment: The question [**Using Fractions in Python**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809633/using-fractions-in-python) may help.

Comment: Doesn't really help me no. But Thanks.